# Thread safety of Object array returned by external webservice

Tags: arrays, multithreading, object, thread-safety, c#-3.0

I am consuming a web service and calling a method which is returning an object array as below.
Is it thread safe or do I need to lock it before getting the value?

> > class WebClient {
> >
> > public string GetInfo()  {  Enternalwebservice extWeb = new ExternalWebservice();
>
> Person[] p = extWeb.GetEmployeeData();
>
> > string info = p[0].name + p[1].Age;
> >
> > return info;  }
> >
> > }
>
> // calling webclient class from multiple threads , as below.
>
> > WebClient wc = new WebClient();  wc.GetInfo();

since object arrays are not thread safe do it need to lock it before reading the array.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be thread-safe? Any concrete suspicion?

Answer (score 0):

Person[] p will be in Thread local storage and scoped to that thread.  It is not being shared by the threads and therefore does not need any synchronization around it.